Flutter can't listen to Document in Firebase
hey i am currently trying to read a list of documents from Firebase in Flutter and initialise a listener for them.
For this I have written a method that accepts a List
these strings are the ids to the documents within a collection
the first readout works great, no errors occur and all data is saved correctly. However, if I now change the data in the Firebase database, the following error appears in the console of the app: Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.
As I have already read the document using exactly this method, this cannot be correct, so what am I doing wrong?
Here is the Method I use for this:
void initListeners(List<String> listIds) {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    for (var id in listIds) {
      db.collection('documents').doc(id).snapshots().listen((event) {
        if (event.exists) {
          final document = Document.fromJson(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>, id);
          if(isDocumentAvailable(id)) {
            updateDocument(document);
          } else{
            addDocument(document);
          }
        } else {
          print("Document $id does not exist");
        }
      }, onError: (error) {
        // Handle errors, such as document not found
        print('Error loading document $id: $error');
      });
    }
  }


Are you getting the listIds from Firebase directly?

yes, i have the list ids in another document but since i get all the results the first time i call the method and this error only occurs when something is changed in the document i am 100% sure that the ids are all correct

If you're getting the IDs from another document, and since in Mongo, relationships are not constrained like in a relational database, there could be a single id in there that actually doesn't have a document for it.

@Abbas for my testing i currently have only one document and this is shown propperly in my ui

I think the problem is not with reading the database, but with writing to it. Could it be that you have a database write in the addDocument(document); method?
This error can also occur if a document is to be written and it does not exist, so you should check again whether you are not using a write option somewhere. This is why it works the first time you read it and then no longer.

Oh yes I used the wrong method and instead of adding them to the list I tried to upload the document ernet to the db and create a new listener. Thanks for the help
